# How to remove Saturday and Sunday between two dates and count total days

Tags: php, laravel, date

2019-03-01 to 2019-04-04  remove Saturday and Sunday  between two dates and count total Days

Comment: I don't think it's a duplicate, since it is addressed for Laravel, which uses extensively Carbon, a nice wrapper around Dates. 
So the answer to this is achieved with few lines of code (have a look at my answer).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [Carbon Docs](https://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/)

```
CarbonPeriod::macro('countWeekdays', function () {
    return $this->filter('isWeekday')->count();
});
echo CarbonPeriod::create('2019-03-01', '2019-04-04')->countWeekdays();
```

Comment: end date is 2019-04-04  ,

Comment: My bad, I fixed that :)

Comment: How about if i want to get array of days excluding weekends
```CarbonPeriod::create('2019-03-01', '2019-04-04')->toArray();```